# Will windows 8 for desktop Share same source code with tablet as well as WP8

Tags: windows-8, windows-phone

I want to know ,whether we can use the same code base for Windows8 of Desktop,laptop and phone(wp8)?

Regards

Rakesh Shankar.p

Comment: [Apparently so](http://www.slashgear.com/windows-phone-8-and-windows-8-get-shared-core-20234871/). Although only time will tell exactly how *much* code can be shared.

Comment: Another question is: will WinRT app work on the desktop?

Comment: no winrt app will only work in metro

Comment: Your question is too vague to be answered.  Windows RT machines can only run apps from the store. Windows 8 machines can run both desktop and apps from the store.  Windows 8 machines come in many form factors - tablet, desktop, all-in-ones or laptop or even a mix of the above.  Windows RT machines are likely to be primarily tablet formfactor machines.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft have proudly announced that they will share the same kernel, and that native coding will become available to developers (again, if you consider Windows Mobile).

How much sharing remains to be seen; at this stage, for an MVVM application, I'd expect the view models (and models) to be sharable with no code changes, and that it would be worth having dedicated views for the smaller resolutions on the phone platform. Of course, my crystal ball is no better than any other non-insider.

It's worth noting that the [minimum screen resolution for metro apps on the desktop is 1024x768](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh780612.aspx#minimum_screen_resolutions), whilst Windows Phone 8 will support 800x480